# Type erasure of member variables

Tags: java, generics

How does type erasure work if there are member variables of collection objects that use generics?

```
public class Pojo {
      private Map<String, String> stringStringMap;

      ...

}
```

Unlike other situations where the type information gets removed, does in this case, type information get retained?

Comment: It's no different from other type erasure.

Comment: Not sure what your question is... why do you think this would be different?

Comment: I'm thinking that there could be difference because if I pass a map as argument to a method, there's no way I can infer the type associated with it however if I pass in an object with a map as member, I can infer the type information.

Comment: *if I pass a map as argument to a method, there's no way I can infer the type associated with it*. You can, if the parameter is parameterized with a specific type, as your member variable is.

Answer (score 0):

The type information is still erased. *At runtime*. The compiler enforces the types, so you cannot programmatically misuse the types, but they will still be unavailable at runtime.

As [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner) points out, you can use reflection to get the declared type of the [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()). In your example, at runtime your type would be `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>`. So, if you have fixed types, it will provide you enough information at runtime. If you are really using generics, however, it will not provide sufficient information. Example:

```
class Pojo<T> {
    Map<String, T> map;
}
```

In this situation, the runtime type you will get using reflection is `java.util.Map<java.lang.String, T>`. This isn't so helpful.

Comment: You can get the [generic type of the field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType()) at runtime.

Comment: You can get the _declared_ type at runtime, but you can't use this method to get the _actual_ type unless the actual type is the same as the declared type, which is sort-of-not-generic.